# -webkit-overflow: touch; stops working when tapping on element outside of scroll container

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, touchmove

I have a really big bug on the iphone, that makes a page unusable and I just can't solve it. I can't find any topic about this issue as well.

I have the following screen:

[image]

In the middle, there is a div, which is set on `-webkit-overflow: auto;` to have smooth scrolling inside this div. The scrolling is working absolutely fine and smooth.

**BUT** only until I do a `touchmove` on another element outside of this div. If I do this and try to scroll the scrollcontainer again, it's frozen and not moving at all. After I tap around a few times on the scroll container it's scrolling again. 
It's losing the scroll focus of the scroll container and trying to scroll a parent.

So, if I do a movement like this:

[image]

This looks like this :

[image]

**Note**: I'm just doing one touchmove from the bottom container into the overflow div. After releasing the finger and then trying to scroll again, it still scrolls the parent div.

I made a short example, so you can have a look with your iphone/phone [here](http://markmaurer.de/scrollissue/).

This issue only appears when using `-webkit-overflow: auto` With normal `overflow: scroll` it's always working but yes... you know how laggy this scrolling feels.

Is there any way to force the scroll focus in the desired container, when you're clicking/tapping a container with `-overflow-scrolling: touch;`?

Comment: That is just how iOS and Safari work. You should be able to see the same result in macOS' Safari, while in Chrome, it should not happen. What you might be able to do is disable body scrolling. That might work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, actually I've blocked body scrolling and it still didn't work.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Thanks but body scroll is absolutely disabled by position fixed, width and height at 100%

Answer (score 15):

The iOS Safari Browser never really gives you full control over the scrolling.
However there is a "hack" you can use, it requires JS tho:

- set `position: fixed` on `body,html`
- As soon as a `touchmove` occurs, set the `body.scrollTop = 0`
  So in your case add:

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove',function (){
  document.body.scrollTop = 0
})
```

[Example page for testing on device](http://manuelotto.com/files/scrollissue.html)

Btw, a better way for handling this would be to make the headline/controls fixed and add a padding to the scrollcontainer. This wouldnt require any JS.
[try it](http://manuelotto.com/files/scrollissue_better.html)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: OMG, googleing for hours and days with no success and now found this simple solution, 1+

Answer (score 2):

I too had this issue, my website worked fine on android phones, but on ios, i had to tap few times, to activate scroll.

I tried disabling body scroll, even tried this

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Lets it scroll lazy */

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto; /* Stops scrolling immediately */
```

I had to use custom scrollbar plugin [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

This plugin completely overrides the system scroll. Here javascript controls the positioning of the scroll content. It makes the content `position:relative` and uses `top` to scroll the content.

If this plugin doesn't work for you, you can try any other scroll plugin. They all work the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, we had a custom scroll in the project and we resign because of few issues. I found that overflow-scrolling: auto resolve issue but then scrolling performance is very bad. I think that this is iOS Safari issue ;/